# Very strange AD authentication issue

Tags: active-directory, authentication

I have a domain controller that is Server 2008 and another that is 2008R2.  I changed my password two weeks ago, and have been able to log into the domain controllers no problem.  When I want to access any other server in the domain (the entire environment is nothing but IIS and SQL servers) I run into a strange issue.  In the RDP client, I use my current credentials.  Using anything else causes it to fail.  Once I hit okay and it starts to login, the server I'm remoting into tells me that my credentials are incorrect, and from there I have to use my old credentials.  Nothing in the logs aside from failed authentication from a bad username/password.  Servers are communicating with the domain controllers.  I don't see anything in the logs on the servers either, although I could be overlooking something.  Has anyone else run into anything similar?

Comment: Are the servers configured to use **only** the Domain Controllers for DNS resolution?

Answer (score 2):

I would verify you are logging in with your domain credentials ie DOMAIN\user and not just user.  I have had this happen to me in the past, I create a local user account with same pw as domain pw.  Changed my domain pw and forget about local account.

Comment: I did double check that, and that was not the case.

Comment: If it allows you to login with your old credentials, I would say those are cached credentials.  Try clearing cached credentials / reboot / try again.  'http://serverfault.com/questions/375036/how-can-i-clear-cached-domain-credentials'

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen if you disconnect from RDP sessions instead of logging off.

Usually it clears up on its own once the Kerberos tickets expire.
If it's not cached credentials, I would double check if Kerberos is operating properly.