# Login to domain account after leaving then rejoining domain

Tags: windows, vpn, domain

I stupidly removed my laptop from the company domain, but have used the local admin account to put myself back on it. It's setup fine, however I am getting the error `there are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request`. I understand that the credentials need caching while connected to the network first, however I wondered if there's a way of doing this without being on the network, seeing as I have been logging in to the account for years with no problem, but just temporarily knocked myself off the domain?

Or, is this cache cleared, and I'll need to go login again to get on the domain?

I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cached credentials are saved in a hidden registry setting. 
Unfortunately when you removed your computer from the domain, upon reboot these registry entries were cleared. Meaning the cache no longer exists.

If your concern is continuing your work without having to hop by the office, you can always take control of the old working folders of your company profile using a local administrator, these files will still exist.
[Converting to local profile](http://www.shofkom.com/2009/03/14/how-to-convert-your-domain-profile-to-a-local-profile/)

You can find more information about the registry cache here:
[How can I clear cached domain credentials?](https://serverfault.com/questions/375036/how-can-i-clear-cached-domain-credentials)

Comment: Thanks @reace, I'll just have to travel to the office then, and learn my mistake :)